# ics attachment not present in gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, icalendar

I have implemented a calendar in my website (Ruby on Rails) and i have also successfully generated an .ics file. I want to send this file as an attachment in an email.

I have set the mime as **text/calendar**

I also set the content_type as **multipart/alternative**

The attachment is sent successfully in the email on all major email clients except **gmail**

How to make the .ics attachment appear in the email. has anyone faced this kind of a problem before. I checked in various google help forums and many have faced this issue, but no concrete solution has been found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Gmail, click the "more" down arrow. One of the options is "Show original". Select that.

When the window opens, scroll down. You should see the VCalendar area. Gmail is ignoring it.

In this area, look for the line that starts as "Organizer;" If you are listed as the organizer, then gmail ignores the ics file. This is a "feature"

We built a web page for ourselves that we copy that text into and it strips that line out and re-emails the ics to us. Then it works fine. (with just a little more work, you could set up an email intercept wherein you forward that email to someplace where you have a parser that grabs the VCalendar, strips out the organizer, and emails it back to you.

We asked Google to put a feature request in to change this, but it's unlikely to happen.

Good Luck.

Comment: This avoided what would be a very, very painful debugging session. Thank you.